# numpy.array with elements of different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to have a numpy array of two another arrays (each of them has different shape). As I know, for this reason one must use: `dtype = object` in the definition of the main array.

For example, let us define (in Python 2.7) our arrays as

```
     a0 = np.arange(2*2).reshape(2,2)
     a1 = np.arange(3*3*2).reshape(3,3,2)
     b = np.array([a0,a1], dtype = object)
```

This works perfect: `b[1]` is the same as `a1`. But if I change the dimension in `a0` from (2,2) to (3,3) something strange happens:

```
     a0 = np.arange(3*3).reshape(3,3)
     a1 = np.arange(3*3*2).reshape(3,3,2)
     b = np.array([a0,a1], dtype = object)
```

This time `b[1]` and `a1` are not equal, they even have different shapes. What is the reason of this strange behavior?

Perhaps there is a completely different solution for me. But I don't want to use lists or tuples because I want to allow addition such as `b + b`. It is clear that I can write my own class for this purpose but is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you explicitly want an objects array, you can create an empty array with type object first and assign to it:

```
x = empty(5, dtype=object)
x[0] = zeros((3,3))
x[1] = zeros((3,2)) #does not merge axes.
x[2] = eye(4)
x[3] = ones((2,2))*2
x[4] = arange(10).reshape((5,2))

>>> x+x
array([array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]),
   array([[ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.]]),
   array([[ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.]]),
   array([[ 4.,  4.],
   [ 4.,  4.]]),
   array([[ 0,  2],
   [ 4,  6],
   [ 8, 10],
   [12, 14],
   [16, 18]])], dtype=object)
```

You will have to fill all elements before you can perform arithmetic, or grow the element from size zero using np.append.

Comment: In your example it is not possible to perform arithmetic for the whole array `x`. For instance, `x+x` won't work.

Comment: Yes you can! You just have to fill all the elements 0..4, as I said (but only gave example for the first two).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a strange behavior, it's the way you use numpy that's weird to me.

numpy merges dimension as much as it can. That's the default behavior and is what expected when working with arrays. In the first example, all the dimensions of `a0` and `a1` are different. numpy is forced to use only the first dimension. So if we look at `b.shape` in the first example, we'll see `(2,)`.

On the second example, `a0` and `a1` has the same dimension size all the way to the last dimension. So numpy merges those levels. If you'd look at `b.shape` here, you'll see `(2,3,3)`, since the second and third dimension are of the same size.